# Pass in function to be evaluated for K8s Commands list

Tags: java, kubernetes, jvm

is it possible to pass a function as the value in a K8s' pod command for evaluation? I am passing in JVM arguments to set the MaxRAM parameter and  would like to read the cgroups memory to ascertain a value for the argument

This is an example of what I'm trying to do

```
- command:
  - /opt/tools/Linux/jdk/openjdk1.8.0_181_x64/bin/java
  - -XX:MaxRAM=$(( $(cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes) * 70/100 ))
```

Unfortunately the above doesn't work and fails with the following error:

```
Improperly specified VM option 'MaxRAM=$(( $(cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes) * 100 / 70 ))'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Is this doable? If so, what's the right way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is shell syntax so you need to run a shell to interpret it.

```
command:
- sh
- -c
- |
  exec /opt/tools/Linux/jdk/openjdk1.8.0_181_x64/bin/java -XX:MaxRAM=$(( $(cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes) * 70/100 ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Reasonably recent versions of the JVM have direct support for understanding the container memory limits.  If you can update to at least Java 8u191 then [it supports the current set of relevant JVM options](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u191-relnotes-5032181.html#JDK-8146115).  You can set:

```yaml
- command:
  - /opt/tools/Linux/jdk/openjdk1.8.0_251_x64/bin/java
  - -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=70.0
```